# Dockerfile, switch between dev / prod

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker, i've done their tutorial and some others things on the web, but that's all.. So I guess I'm doing this in a very wrong way..

It has been one day since I'm looking for a way to publish a Dockerfile that will either launch `npm run dev` or `npm start`, depends on the prod or dev environnement.

## Playground

What I got so far :

```
# Specify the node base image version such as node:<version>
FROM node:10

# Define environment variable, can be overight by runinng docker run with -e "NODE_ENV=prod"
ENV NODE_ENV dev

# Set the working directory to /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install nodemon for hot reload
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && \
    npm cache clean --force

# Set the port used by the app
EXPOSE 8080

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Launch the app
CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js" ]
```

From what i've saw in the www, is that people tend to use bash for doing that kind of operation or mount a volume in the docker-compose, however it looks so much verbosity for just doing an if else condition inside a Dockerfile.

## Goal

Without using any other file(keep things simple)

What i'm looking for is something like :

```
if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "dev" ]; then 
   CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"] // dev env
else
   CMD ["node", "server.js"] // prod env
fi
```

Maybe I'm wrong, any good advice about how doing such a thing in docker would be nice.

Also, nota that I'm not sure how to allow reload in my container when modifying a file in my host, I guess it's all about volume, but again not sure how to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to apply this logic in Dockerfile syntax, everything should be at the entrypoint script. To avoid using other files, you can implement this logic in one-line bash script:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ['-c','if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "dev" ]; then nodemon server.js; else node server.js; fi']
```

Comment: thanks, ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"], should be double quote to works, for someone next :) https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30752

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` so you can execute a bash script inside the container as the first command.

```
ENTRYPOINT["your/script.sh"]
CMD["your/script.sh"]
```

in your script do your thing!

Even you dont need to pass the env variable since in the script you can access it.